# Combine two files having same format based on values of a specific column

Tags: bash, command-line, files

I have two files **stat_1.txt** & **stat_2.txt**. As follows:

job_id | execution_time

--------+--------------------

**12345**  |    00:04:42.454282

12346  |    00:03:26.360487

====================

job_id | execution_time

--------+--------------------

12347  |    00:01:43.634521

**12345**  |    00:02:34.321451

There are of course thousands more records in each file. I need to arrange in a single file the **job_id** which are present in both files, for making a comparative analysis of execution times. (similar to what we might do in a table join.) How do I do this? I'm sure there must be an elegant way in bash.

The files are **not ordered** by job_id. There are some job_id which are present in only one file but not the other.
(Sorry if the tables above look sloppy. I'm not familiar with the formatting, and I'm in bit of a hurry.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}
{k=$1$2;print k,a[k],$3;delete a[k]}
END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' test1 test2
```

test1 and test2 are the two files to combined

Here is the example :

```
[xxxx@xxxx test]$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2]=$3;next}
                  {k=$1$2;print k,a[k],$3;delete a[k]}
                  END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' test1 test2

job_id | execution_time execution_time
--------+--------------------
12347 |  00:01:43.634521
12345 | 00:04:42.454282 00:02:34.321451
12346 | 00:03:26.360487
```